# combine "while" and "for" loop in C, for user to choose to loop forever or loop a number of times

Tags: c, optimization

I would like to combine a for loop and while loop, where user can choose to loop until it passes or loop a number of time and return fail if it doesn't pass:

```
uint8_t SomeFunc(uint32_t LoopCnt, unit32_t LoopForever)
{

    uint8_t result = FAIL;
    if(LoopForever != FALSE)LoopCnt = -1; /*max out LoopCnt if LoopForever is set*/

    do{
        for(i = 0; i < LoopCnt; i++){
            result = Func();
            if (result == PASS) break;
        }

    }while(LoopForever & (result == FAIL))/* do while loopforever is set and the result is fail */

    return result;

}
```

Is there a better way to write this? with better performance and less code size? it's in C. T**he solution can use no loop to achieve basically anything you can comeup with that do the same logic**.
Thanks

Comment: Hmm, if code was `SomeFunc(uint64_t LoopCnt)`, could be called with `SomeFunc(UINT64_MAX)` and effect a forever loop.  Ah, I see that now that is what OP is doing with 32-bit.

Comment: `LoopForever & (result == FAIL)`, is this what you want? Or is it `&&`? The `()` is unnecessary.

Comment: Please don't make code corrections to the post!

Comment: user1998844, As `result` is a `uint8_t`, looks like `result` can have other values than  `PASS` and `FAIL`.   Does `Func()` return other than `PASS` and `FAIL`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Just PASS and FAIL

Comment: The audience for this question was unnecessarily narrowed by [embedded] and [greenhills] tags (removed).  In this case the nature of the target platform or the toolchain used are entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really 'need' to combine `while` and `for`?

```
uint8_t SomeFunc(uint32_t LoopCnt, uint32_t LoopForever) {
    
    uint8_t result = FAIL;
    
    while (result == FAIL && (LoopForever || LoopCnt--)) {
        result = Func();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nice simplification (assuming `FALSE == 0`).

Comment: Which is standard conversion of int to boolean.  I don't know why the function parameter isn't bool FWIW.  Or why PASS/FAIL aren't a bool for that matter.

Comment: True, better as `bool result_pass = false;` or `bool result_fail = true;` (depending on `Func()` return polarity) would have made more sense.

Comment: Why invert convention?  PASS == true, FAIL == false.  Simple.

Comment: It is reasonable to consider the definition of `PASS, FAIL` is not adjustable - likely one is 0 and the other non-zero.  The initial value of `result_...` as `false` then needs to match the `FAIL` state.

Answer (score 2):

Candidate alternative assuming `result` can only have values of `PASS` or `FAIL`.

When `LoopCnt == UINT32_MAX`, `i <= LoopCnt;` is forever true.

Code uses `<=` test instead of `<`.  We simple need to test the `LoopCnt == 0` case and then decrement `LoopCnt`.

```
uint8_t SomeFunc(uint32_t LoopCnt, unit32_t LoopForever) {
  uint8_t result = FAIL;
  if (LoopCnt > 0 || LoopForever != FALSE) {
    LoopCnt--;
    if (LoopForever != FALSE) {
      LoopCnt = UINT32_MAX;
    }
    for (uint32t i = 0; i <= LoopCnt; i++){
      result = Func();
      if (result == PASS) {
        return result;  // Return now.
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

The advantage of [@Dave Meehan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72071459/2410359) good answer is clarity, yet with 3 tests per iteration.   This code has 2 iterations per loop.  Only in select cases [e.g. 3% of the time](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/94903) are the fewer tests preferable.